# Validating user input - only characters

Tags: java, validation, user-input

How to validate my user input for only characters?

```java
package com.company;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("C-cement G-gravel S-sand ");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Choose a sack:");
        String sack = (scanner.next());
        int namelenght = sack.length();

        do {
            System.out.println("This is invalid, please try again");
            sack = scanner.next();

        } while ((!scanner.nextLine().matches("[a-zA-Z]+")) || (namelenght >= 1));


    }
}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Why do you print _"This is invalid"_ immediately?

Comment: It sounds like you're asking how to validate that your application's user is only responding to "Choose a sack" with a word composed of capital and lower case letters. As written, your program is pretty close, but as Thomas said above, it might help to clarify *precisely* what you're asking, such as "why isn't my code doing X that I think it should be doing?"

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("C-cement G-gravel S-sand ");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Choose a sack:");
        String sack;
        while(true) {
            try {
                sack = scanner.nextLine();
                if(!sack.matches("[a-zA-Z]+") || sack.length() > 1) {
                    throw new InputMismatchException();
                }
                break;
            }
            catch(InputMismatchException e) {
                System.out.println("Invalid Input! Try again:");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("You've entered: " + sack);

    }
}
```

This will only accept a String as input that has length 1 and only contains letters.